# Split a paragraph in Hindi without punctuation into sentences in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unicode

I was trying to split a Paragraph written in the Hindi language into sentences. The problem is that not all the sentences in that paragraph are ending with '|' so the idea to use split() failed. Can anyone please recommend any solution?

Here is the paragraph:

> विकिपीडिया सभी विषयों पर प्रामाणिक और उपयोग, परिवर्तन व पुनर्वितरण के लिए स्वतन्त्र ज्ञानकोश बनाने का एक बहुभाषीय प्रकल्प है। यह यथासम्भव निष्पक्ष दृष्टिकोण वाली सूचना प्रसारित करने के लिए कृतसंकल्प है। सर्वप्रथम अंग्रेज़ी विकिपीडिया जनवरी 2001 में आरम्भ किया गया था, और हिन्दी विकिपीडिया का शुभारम्भ जुलाई 2003 में हुआ। सहायता पृष्ठ पर जाएं और प्रयोगस्थल में प्रयोग करके देखें कि आप स्वयं किसी लेख को कैसे परिवर्तित कर सकते हैं।

Here is my code:

```
import codecs

class Tokenizer():
def __init__(self,text):
    self.text=text.decode('utf-8')
    self.clean_text()
    self.sentences=[]
    self.final_list=[]
    self.bsentences=[]
    self.asentences=[]
    self.final_sentences=self.bsentences+self.asentences

def readFromFile(self,filename):
    f=codecs.open(filename,encoding='utf-8')
    self.text=f.read()
    self.clean_text()

def print_sentences(self,sentences):
        for i in self.sentences:
            print i.encode('utf-8')

def cleanText(self):
    text=self.text
    text=re.sub(r'(\d+)',r'',text)
    text=text.replace(u',','')
    text=text.replace(u'"','')
    text=text.replace(u'"','')
    text=text.replace(u':','')
    text=text.replace(u"'",'')
    text=text.replace(u"‘‘",'')
    text=text.replace(u"’’",'')
    text=text.replace(u"''",'')
    text=text.replace(u".",'')
    self.text=text

def getSentence(self):
    text=self.text
    self.bsentences=text.split(u"।")
    sw=codecs.open("stopwords.txt",encoding='utf-8')
    stopwords=[x.strip() for x in sw.readlines()]
    sentences=[s for s in sw.readlines() if s in enumerate(stopwords)]
    return self.final_sentences

t=Tokenizer('')
t.readFromFile('sample.txt')
t.getSentences()
t.print_sentences()
```

Comment: pyhton 3 or 2.7? or do you need cross-version code? please do not tag.-spam

Comment: I apologise if you think i have spammed. But for me, i am fine with any version.

Answer (score 0):

```
def sentencesplit_hindi(paragraph):
        import re
        sentenceEnders = re.compile(ur"""(?:(?<=[\|!?])|(?<=[\।]))\s+""",re.MULTILINE |re.UNICODE)
        sentenceList = sentenceEnders.split(paragraph)
        return sentenceList
```

Comment: Hi @gagan_soni, can you please add some explanation to your code? Thanks:)

Comment: This answer does not solve my question. Not all sentences will have full stop. Sometimes we mistakingly write sentences without full stop and i would like to know the solution of that problem.

Comment: this is user related problem. Every sentence should be ended with full stop in any language. Machine can't predict where a sentence is ending. But you can try hindi auxiliary verbs to determine sentence ending.  for examples: "था, थी, थे, है, हैं" etc.. this is not a good and permanent solution.

Comment: That's the approach i wanted. Please think before downvoting. Hope you understand. The solution you provided can also be done in one line <code>sentence.split('|')</code>